# j2me + javax.microedition.midlet.MediaException:Sounds not allowed

Tags: java-me, midp, midlet, mmapi, series-40

I am trying to Play MP3 and getting unexpected errors.
I have tested my app before 3 days

which was working perfect on my device

but now even that same jar file is giving me following error.

```
javax.microedition.midlet.MediaException:Sounds not allowed
```

error is coming when it executes this line
    player.prefetch()

I am testing this app on **Nokia 5200** and **Nokia 5130**

what could be problem?
Please guide me.
Following is my code.

```
public class PlayAudioMidlet extends MIDlet {

private Display display;
AudioPlayer ap;

public void startApp() {

display = Display.getDisplay(this);
ap = new AudioPlayer(this, display);
display.setCurrent(ap); // display a subclass of Form named as AudioPlayer
}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
notifyDestroyed();
}
}

class AudioPlayer extends Form
implements CommandListener, PlayerListener {

PlayAudioMidlet midlet;
private Display display;
private Command play, stop, exit, forward, backward;
private Player player;

public AudioPlayer(PlayAudioMidlet midlet, Display display) {

super("");
this.midlet = midlet;
this.display = Display.getDisplay(midlet);

play = new Command("Play", Command.OK, 0);
stop = new Command("Stop", Command.STOP, 0);
exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);

addCommand(play);
addCommand(stop);
addCommand(forward);
addCommand(backward);
addCommand(exit);

setCommandListener(this);
}

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {

if (c == play) {
try {
//System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
playAudio();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
} else if (c == stop) {
player.close();
}
}

public void playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData) {
}

public void playAudio() {
int i = 0;
try {
**//Even this commented line doesn't work
//player = Manager.createPlayer(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/alert.mp3"), "audio/mpeg");
player = Manager.createPlayer("file:///E:/Sound/alert1.mp3");**
player.addPlayerListener(this);
// player.setLoopCount(-1);
player.prefetch();
player.realize();
player.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
Alert a = new Alert("");
a.setString("Error "+e.toString());
a.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
display.setCurrent(a);

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

due to some problem in my code, device was not able to play any kind of music.
So I just restored my device with factory settings. And it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the phone's profile (i.e. General, Silent etc)  recently? Go into the settings of your profile and check if the "Application Tones" are allowed.